# what is the maximum life-time for Let's Encrypt certificates

Tags: tls, certificates, letsencrypt

[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is one of the most popular TLS Certificate Authorities. I have conflicting information about its certificates life-time. In this [link](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/09/why-90-days.html) it says 90-days. In one research paper I read 1 month. Can you please inform me what is the correct maximum life-time for Let's Encrypt issues certificates?

Comment: I wonder if the research paper confused how long before expiry renewals happen with valudity of the cert. Cert validity is definately 90 days.

Comment: Perhaps the paper was suggesting to renew it every month rather than it expires every month?

Comment: Can you give the references of that research paper?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ## What is the lifetime for Let’s Encrypt certificates? For how long are they valid?
>
> Our certificates are valid for 90 days. You can read about why here.
>
> There is no way to adjust this, there are no exceptions. We recommend automatically renewing your certificates every 60 days.

[Reading the FAQ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) **should** be the ***first*** thing you do when you have questions about a product or a service.

Comment: Thanks. I did read this. But as I said, I found another research paper saying it is one month. I thought the FAQ can be outdated.

Comment: There is no reason to believe the FAQ to be outdated. They explicitly mention 90 days, and that 60 days is recommended renewal time. You can also check their own certificate, for letsencrypt.org, which is issued by themselves, and is indeed 90 days validity.